# Can .searchable be used to search by property of object in list (swiftUI)

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI list which consists of objects instead of plain text. Is there a way to use `.searchable` to add a search bar that will filter by an objects property, such as its title, or if not, an alternate way to add a search bar to this list? Thanks.

Comment: Very possible. Here's an example: https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-searchable/